# Centering section

Tags: html, css, center, margins

I got problem with centering the div `#offer` within the section `.tight`. I don't want to use `position: absolute;` because of possibility of correct displaying site in `1024px` width screens.

Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="main">
    <section class="tight">
        <div id="offers">
        <article class="offer">
            <div id="offer_stats"></div>
            text
        </article>
        <article class="offer">
            <div id="offer_comp"></div>
            text
        </article>
        <article class="offer last">
            <div id="offer_time"></div>
            text
        </article> 
        </div>
    </section>
 </section>
```

And the CSS:

```
section.main {
    min-width: 880px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section.tight {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
#offers {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
article.offer {
    float: left;
    min-height: 178px;
    width: 260px;
    color: #59535e;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
article.offer.last {
    padding-right: 0;
}
article.offer div {
    height: 178px;
}
#offer_stats {
    background: url("../images/offer_stats.png") no-repeat;   
}
#offer_comp {
    background: url("../images/offer_comp.png") no-repeat;   
}
#offer_time {
    background: url("../images/offer_time.png") no-repeat;   
}
```

The printscreen:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
section.main {
  width: 880px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It's not the solution, because I want to display the rest of elements default in 1200px width.

Comment: Do you want me to meke jQuery solution? Because you can't center element with `min` & `max` width.

Answer (score 0):

First, i suggest you to remove `float: left;` from `#offers`

```
#offers {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Second, i suggest you to use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` in `article.offer`

```
article.offer {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 178px;
    width: 260px;
    color: #59535e;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLp4Q/)